# How to get related objects from Rally API

Tags: node.js, api, rally

Using the REST api in node.js, I am doing an PortfolioItem/features query and receiving the following example result...

```
{ _rallyAPIMajor: '2',
       _rallyAPIMinor: '0',
       _ref: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature/number',
       _refObjectUUID: '...',
       _objectVersion: '52',
       _refObjectName: 'Product',
       CreationDate: '2013-05-28T15:27:23.920Z',
       _CreatedAt: 'May 28, 2013',
       ObjectID: 112345,
       ObjectUUID: '...',
       VersionId: '52',
       Subscription: [Object],
       Workspace: [Object],
       Changesets: [Object],
       Connections: [Object],
       CreatedBy: [Object],
       Description: '',
       Discussion: [Object],
       DisplayColor: '#848689',
       Expedite: false,
       FormattedID: 'F6',
       LastUpdateDate: '2016-06-23T17:53:20.456Z',
       LatestDiscussionAgeInMinutes: null,
       Milestones: [Object],
       Name: 'Product',
       Notes: '',
       Owner: [Object],
       Project: [Object],
       Ready: false,
       RevisionHistory: [Object], ...
```

I am interested in getting the Project Name and the Owner Name from the `Project: [Object]` and `Owner: [Object]`.

Using `Fetch: 'true'`, to retrieve all fields on the object, does not include the `_ref: (a url)` or the `_refObjectUUID: (internal object ID)` for project or the owner.

I am interested in the `Project:_refObjectName` and the `Owner:_refObject` name.

I don't know how to get to these other objects from a Feature.

Comment: Please format in-line code with grave quotes ( \` ) so it looks like this: `code`. It will make the question easier to read.

Comment: I will try this.  Maybe [Object] is actually a reference to a collection of objects.  I'll try to read that content, and follow-up post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just add the fields you would like hydrated to your fetch.  In general, fetch=true will be slow, so only include the fields you need.  Fetch cascades, so if you fetch Name you'll get it hydrated on any object that includes that field.

So in your case, something like this:

```
fetch: ['Project', 'Name', 'Owner']
```

_ref and _refObjectName should always be returned for any objects in the response.

Comment: `fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', '_type', 'ObjectID', 'PlannedStartdate', 'PlannedEndDate', 'ActualStartDate', 'ActualEndDate', 'LastUpdateDate',
    'StateChangedDate', 'PreliminaryEstimateValue', 'Project', 'Owner'],`     is returning only `Owner: [Object]` and `Project: [Object]`.  No `Name` for the project.  `[Object]` is a String, not a reference to an object.

Comment: I bet the data is there.  The console.log isn't pretty printing the nested objects, but I bet if you `console.log(result.Project.Name);` it'll be there.  Or pretty print it: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));`

Comment: With proper hydration, this worked using:  `var projectName = result.Results[x].Project.Name;` and  `var
    ownerName = result.Results[x].Owner._refObjectName;`

Answer (score 0):

With proper hydration, this worked using:

`var projectName = result.Results[x].Project.Name;`
`var ownerName = result.Results[x].Owner._refObjectName;`